# Do Phineas and Ferb ever actually get busted in real time?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In every episode I've seen so far, Phineas and Ferb's creations vanish in amusing ways, when their mom gets home. And in one episode they get busted, but it turns out to be a dream. Is there any episode where they actually get busted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question already refers to [the episode “Phineas and Ferb Get Busted!”](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Leave_the_Busting_to_Us!), in which the brothers are busted and sent to a correction facility, but the whole thing turns out to be a dream.  There are at least two other episodes when Mom busts the boys.

1. The boys get busted *twice* in [“Phineas and Ferb's Quantum Boogaloo”](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb%27s_Quantum_Boogaloo).  First, Candace from the future uses a time machine to travel back to the time the boys have built a roller-coaster.  She helps present Mom bust the boys.  However, that ends even worse than in “Phineas and Ferb Get Busted!”, so future Candace works to get those events erased from the timeline using more time travel.  The second bust is when present Phineas and Ferb and Candace travel into the future and meet their Mom.  This is enough proof for Mom that they're time travelers and that Phineas and Ferb made the time machines, so Candace finally gets Mom to bust them.  This, however, all happens in the future where future Phineas and Ferb are grown up, and Mom in the present never finds out about it.  The bust does give Candace some satisfaction though, and a renewed resolve to try to bust her brothers.
2. Another occasion is [“She's the Mayor”](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/She%27s_the_Mayor), in which Mom busts Phineas and Ferb, but then an invention of Doctor Doofenschmirtz misfires and turns time back to before most of the episode has happened, so in the end Mom doesn't remember this.
3. Also notable is [“Invasion of the Ferb Snatchers”](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Ferb_Snatchers), in which Candace and the audience initially believes that Mom sees the rocket in the back yard, but then it turns out that this wasn't Mom, it was a tiny alien disguised as Mom.

> Phineas: No problem, Garbog. I hope you finished your study on the habits of the human female parental unit.

Interestingly, the boys don't get busted in “Last Day of Summer”, despite that many events in the episode are undone once again by an invention of Dr. Doofenschmirtz.  There are also two memorable occasions when Candace gets busted, but I don't think these answer your question.

Comment: Alright... The quantum thing sounds promising, but your answer essentially confirms that Candace never gets a full victory

Comment: Going on 4 years now and, "a renewed resolve to try to but her brothers" hasn't been questioned? (at the end of point #1). I'd offer up an edit, but I'm not sure what it should be...

Answer (score 2):

I want to add the "[Backyard Hodge Podge](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Backyard_Hodge_Podge)" from season 4.

The Mum (after a work loaded time) steps outside into the backyard and see a very big roller-coaster like invention. Candace walks aside her, but is at exactly this time hit by the "Eye-Fog-inator". As the Mum asks Candace "Do you see what I see" she must answer "No Mum, I see nothing" and the Mum goes back inside, thinking she hallucinates...

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other episodes people have mentioned, they also technically get busted in Season 2 Episode 26, in the “Perry Lays an Egg” segment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe what they were busted for and by whom?

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually in the episode "Interview With a Platypus" mom saw their invention and it didn't vanish and time wasn't reversed or anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you describe what the invention is, and what their mom's reaction was?